# How to add fade onclick event to specific particle (data object) within canvas system?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, dom-events, particle-system

I want to click on one of the floating particles, upon clicking it, I want the particle colour to change from light grey to blue and then fade. Particle quantity is set as 100, as particles are clicked on to fade away particle quantity decreases. I'm unfamiliar with js, just started learning about canvas and particle systems yesterday, this is code from a pen that I've changed a bit and would like to add more changes to by adding the *fade onclick* event. I know that the particles within canvas are under one variable that defines them altogether, I don't know how to isolate one particle in the canvas to work with as I would need to know it's exact `x,y` coordinates.

Would I then have to find the coordinates for all 100 particles and add elements to each individual particle- and how do I do this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var PARTICLE_QUANT = 100;
  var FPS = 60;
  var BOUNCE = -1;
  var PARTICLE_COLOR = '#ced4d4';
  var ARC_RADIUS = 12;

  var Particles = function($element) {
    if ($element.length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    this.$element = $element;
    this.lastTimeStamp = null;
    this.particles = [];
    this.init();
  };

  var proto = Particles.prototype;
  proto.init = function() {
    this.createChildren()
    .layout()
    .enable();
  };

  proto.createChildren = function() {
    this.canvas = this.$element[0];
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.canvasWidth = this.canvas.width;
    this.canvasHeight = this.canvas.height;
    this.lastTimeStamp = new Date().getTime();

    return this;

  };


  proto.layout = function() {
    window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
      return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame;
    })();

    return this;
  };

  proto.removeChildren = function() {
    this.context = null;
    this.canvasWidth = null;
    this.canvasHeight = null;
    this.lastTimeStamp = null;

    return this;
  };

  proto.enable = function() {
    this.createParticleData();
    this.renderLoop();
  };

  proto.createParticleData = function() {
    var i = 0;
    var l = PARTICLE_QUANT;

    for (; i < l; i++) {
      this.particles[i] = {};
      this.setParticleData(this.particles[i]);
    }
  };


  proto.setParticleData = function(particle) {
    particle.x = Math.random() * this.canvasWidth;
    particle.y = Math.random() * this.canvasHeight;
    particle.vx = (Math.random()) - 0.5;
    particle.vy = (Math.random()) - 0.5;
  };

  proto.update = function() {
    var i = 0;
    var l = PARTICLE_QUANT;

    for (; i < l; i++) {
      var particle = this.particles[i];

      particle.x += particle.vx;
      particle.y += particle.vy;

      if (particle.x > this.canvasWidth) {
        particle.x = this.canvasWidth;
        particle.vx *= BOUNCE;
      } else if (particle.x < 0) {
        particle.x = 0;
        particle.vx *= BOUNCE;
      }

      if (particle.y > this.canvasHeight) {
        particle.y = this.canvasHeight;
        particle.vy *= BOUNCE;
      } else if (particle.y < 0) {
        particle.y = 0;
        particle.vy *= BOUNCE;
      }
    }
  };


  proto.draw = function() {
    var i = 0;

    if (!this.context) {
      return;
    }

    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvasWidth, this.canvasHeight);
    this.context.fillStyle = PARTICLE_COLOR;

    for (; i < PARTICLE_QUANT; i++) {
      var particle = this.particles[i];
      this.context.save();
      this.context.beginPath();
      this.context.arc(particle.x, particle.y, ARC_RADIUS, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      this.context.fill();
      this.context.restore();
    }
  };

  proto.renderLoop = function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(this.renderLoop.bind(this));
    this.update();
    this.draw();
  };

  var particles = new Particles($('#js-particles'));

  //Everything above works, it is what comes next (below), is this the right  approach?

  var elem = document.getElementById('js-particles'),
      elemLeft = elem.offsetLeft,
      elemTop = elem.offsetTop,
      context = elem.getContext('2d'),
      elements = [];

  // Add event listener for `click` events.
  elem.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var x = event.pageX - elemLeft,
        y = event.pageY - elemTop;

    // Collision detection between clicked offset and element.
    elements.forEach(function(element) {
      if (y > element.top && y < element.top + element.height && x > element.left && x < element.left + element.width)
        });

    }, false);

    // Add element.
    elements.push({
      colour: '#05EFFF',
      width: 150,
      height: 100,
      top: 20,
      left: 15
    });

    // Render elements.
    elements.forEach(function(element) {
      context.fillStyle = element.colour;
      context.fillRect(element.left, element.top, element.width, element.height);
    });
```

```html
<canvas id="js-particles" class="particles" width="960" height="960">
  <p>text appears if browser doesn 't support canvas</p>
</canvas>
```

Comment: Please do not put all your code. Create a minimal verifiable sample and share it

Comment: Also, why are you loading 2 jQuery?

Comment: @Rajesh I'm sorry, first time sharing code on stackoverflow, is this better?

Comment: Apologies, but the point was, it is very difficult to read 100 lines of code (non executable) and understand the issue.

Comment: You must listen for mouse events on the canvas element itself and then hit-test every particle to see if the mouse is over it. Then react by re-rendering that particle as desired. Here is Documentation on [Collisions & Intersections](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html5-canvas/5017/collisions-and-intersections#t=201611151645410211917) to get you started with hit-testing.